# Simple Failover for IIS and MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, iis, web-applications, failover, redundancy

I have a client with a .Net 1.0 web app that uses IIS and a SQL 2000 database. It is hosted with a shared hosting service and does get not much traffic (a few visitors a day tops). The hosting has occasional downtime, of course, and the client has asked me if I can setup a redundant system to reduce downtime to negligible.

What is the simplest/cheapest improvement I could make to this setup that would satisfy what the client is asking for?

I was imagining hosting the web app and db with 2 different services and adding some logic to the app hand off requests to whichever web server & database are up, but I'm worried about the complexities of keeping the databases in sync.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Switch hosts and go with one that offers this type of hosting.

Comment: Do you gave an example? Thanks

Comment: If you are talking about having so much downtime that with 5 visitors a day, so maybe total site use is 30 minutes a day, your host is not reliable enough, then you are better off just switching hosts to basically any decent hosting company that can provide an SLA with 99.9% uptime. There is a boundary between needing redundancy and just needing a single point of failure that is decent in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend putting and apache2 server with mod_jk in front of the two IIS endpoints.